# Ruby access instance method from another class

Tags: ruby, class, hash, instance-variables

```
class Room #room.rb
    def initialize(capacity)
        @capacity = capacity
        @occupants = []
    end

    def capacity
        @capacity
    end

    def occupants
        @occupants
    end

    def full?
        return false if occupants.length < capacity
        return true if occupants.length == capacity      
    end

    def add_occupant(name)
        if !self.full?
            occupants << name
            return true
        end
        return false
    end

end
```

```
#hotel.rb
require_relative "room"

class Hotel
    def initialize(name, hash)
        @rooms = {}
        hash.each do |room_name,capacity|
            @rooms[room_name] = Room.new(capacity)
        end
    end

    def rooms
        @rooms
    end

    def check_in(person, room_name)
        open_room = rooms[room_name].add_occupant(person)
    end

end

hotel = Hotel.new("some hotel", "Basement"=>4, "Attic"=>1)
rooms = hotel.instance_variable_get(:@rooms)
hotel.check_in("Rick", "Attic")
```

In the `def check_in` instance method, the spec requires call Room#add_occupant on the correct Room instance.

My first thought was to define Room.new for add_occupants, so I used `rooms[room_name] = Rooms.new.add_occupants(person)`. However this would not work due to the arguments (given 0 expected 1)

The solution that met the spec was `rooms[room_name].add_occupant(person)`

How does this allow access to the instance method `def add_occupant` in Room class from the `def check_in` instance method in the Hotel Class?

I have come to realize that rooms is a hash with values that are instance variables from the Rooms class. Is it because I have defined `@rooms[room_name] = Room.new(capacity)` in my initialize method, which allows access to Rooms class?

Comment: Please properly format your question for readability. It helps us help you. See "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)". Also see "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" as it looks like you can reduce your example code. Put in the very minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: For trivial cases consider using [`attr_reader`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader).

Comment: _"values that are instance variables from the Rooms class"_ – just "instances", not "instance variables". BTW, it might be easier to think in terms of message passing. `hotel.check_in(...)` send the message `check_in` to the `hotel` object. `rooms` sends the message `rooms` to `self` (which returns a hash), `...[room_name]` sends the message `[]` to that hash etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because I have defined @rooms[room_name] = Room.new(capacity) in my initialize method, which allows access to Rooms class?

Exactly, you understand :)

If we add some logging, it's easy to see ..

```
    def check_in(person, room_name)
        puts rooms[room_name].class # => Room
        open_room = rooms[room_name].add_occupant(person)
    end
```

As we see with `puts`, `rooms[room_name]` returns an instance of `Room`, therefore we are allowed to call the `add_occupant` method.

Think of the `rooms` hash as the hotel registration book.